# Alignment of South American and Egyptian Pyramids

Tags: science, egypt, south-america, north-africa, pyramids

I don't remember when and where I hear, but I remember something like this: several pyramids in Egypt are aligned with pyramids in South America .

That is, in South America are several (if correctly remember, 3) pyramid located in one straight line, and in Egypt are also 3 pyramid located in one straight line, and these all 6 pyramid are also located in straight line.

Please see picture

So, question is, is this true? 
I am searched, but not found

[image]

Comment: Downvote for questions without evidence of preliminary research.  The simplest first step would be to search for a map of all the pyramids in the world.

Comment: Yes, the pyramids have to be aligned this way otherwise the aliens would not be able to land their space ships.

Comment: @Tyler Durden, if this is not trolling, then this looks like good answer

Comment: OP's question ends on a very existential note.

Comment: On my opinion, pseudo-science is not within the scope of this list.

Comment: My girlfriend the historian says "Von Danieken".  I concur with @twosheds, but not all who wander are lost.

Comment: Is a "straight" line drawn on that map projection even straight?

Answer (score 2):

The three great pyramids of Giza are not in a straight line.

The two largest pyramids are arranged Northeast-Southwest of one another.

The 225-degree line of bearing through Giza (NE-SW) does not even pass through South America at all, much less through Peru. The yellow line below is this bearing:

[image: sw of Giza]

Comment: "The three great pyramids of Giza are not in a straight line."
are your sure?

http://www.scottcreighton.co.uk/GHMB-AOM/Giza-Diagonal-TCP.jpg
----------------

https://www.google.ru/maps/place/The+Great+Pyramid+at+Giza/@29.9744596,31.1334118,967m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s0x14584587ac8f291b:0x810c2f3fa2a52424?hl=ru

Comment: @OTARIKI It is true that the southeast corners of the pyramids are colinear, but mathematically speaking it the apex of a pyramid which is considered to be its center. Either way the bearing line does not go through Peru.

Comment: Tyler Durden - Yes, the bearing line does not go through Peru, on my picture red line is wrong, but bearing line does go somewhere in  south brazil, uruguay, argentina or chile.

Comment: @OTARIKI You may be using a map with the wrong projection. I have updated my answer to show the line of bearing southwest from Giza.